# Django: problem trying to post data to django model database

Tags: django

ProgrammingError at /admin/formRegister/formregister/
column formRegister_formregister.password1 does not exist
LINE 1: ...astname", "formRegister_formregister"."username", "formRegis...
^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/formRegister/formregister/
Django Version: 4.0.5
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:
column formRegister_formregister.password1 does not exist
LINE 1: ...astname", "formRegister_formregister"."username", "formRegis...
^
Exception Location: C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Django\django3.9\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 89, in _execute
Python Executable:  C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Django\django3.9\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.13
Python Path:
['C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Django\teluskoa',
'C:\Program '
'Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python39.zip',
'C:\Program '
'Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs',
'C:\Program '
'Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib',
'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0',
'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Django\django3.9',
'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Django\django3.9\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 11 Aug 2022 16:02:26 +0000

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like migrations issue:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thank you. Though i tried migrating the model but i will retry.

Comment: If so, then maybe you have manipulated migration files and it's not creating database properly, or more likely database is broken and you need to drop it and create a new one.